# ruby POST requested Json to structured array or hash for CSV

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, csv, hash

```
{
  "TOTAL" : "520"

  ,

  "PROD_101379" : {
    "IMG" : "1406301107587209.jpg",
    "NAME" : "hello sunny",
    "LINK" : "/product/productDetail.do?seq=101379",
    "SEQ" : "101379",
    "PRICE" : "18000",
    "MILEAGE" : "2"
  }
  ,

  "PROD_101378" : {
    "IMG" : "",
    "NAME" : "special gift",
    "LINK" : "/product/productDetail.do?seq=101378",
    "SEQ" : "101378",
    "PRICE" : "3000",
    "MILEAGE" : "2"
  }
  ,

  "PROD_101376" : {
    "IMG" : "1405020190326241.jpg",
    "NAME" : "it radiant",
    "LINK" : "/product/productDetail.do?seq=101376",
    "SEQ" : "101376",
    "PRICE" : "45000",
    "MILEAGE" : "2"
  }
    ,

  "PAGER" : "&lt;div class=&quot;paging&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:pageForm('0');

}
```

I am learning how to program in Ruby, using Nokogiri gem to parse internet data.

Above data was received after requesting with POST using Net/HTTP, then parsing it with Json gem.

```
JSON.parse(x.body)
```

I am trying to turn that data into CSV like so:

```
IMG | Name | Link | SEQ | Price | Mileage |
```

for each PROD_xxxxxx arrays.

I've read the gem documentation, and looked at other questions here to realize that much like Nokogiri parsing HTML(or more like Array & Hash), I should be able to parse JSON format.

I found that I can get the value of something by:

```
json_parsed["TOTAL"]
```

which would give me "520"

I get use the same approach to get at the "PROD_xxxxxx" nested data, but that would give me only specific nested data for that name.

I would like to be able to loop through them, so I've tried something like

```
json_parsed["PROD*"].each do |each|
```

but looks like this is not the correct way to use the syntax.

If can I loop through each and get "IMG", "NAME", "LINK", ...etc, I am trying to use CSV to:

```
CSV.open(fname,"w") do |csv|
  Json_parsed[each-PROD].each do |each|
   name = each["NAME"]
   img = each["IMG"]
   csv << [name, img]
  end
end
```

However, if there is a better way than the above approach to turn the JSON data into CSV (maybe this is possible as JSON is a structured data, like CSV?) I would appreciate the suggestion.

Thanks,

Comment: do you trying something for achieve?

Comment: [This is not “write the code for me” site](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @mudasobwa I need a direction on how to solve the above problem. Which part of my question is asking for a "write the code for me?" Your comment or a remark isn't very helpful. If you think I should ask in such a way, or share what I have tried, I'll appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: To appreciate my suggestion I would expect you to read the article I linked.

Comment: @Rok , the way is simple: for each attributes of parsed json select all subobjects that starts from PROD and join all attributes of subobjects with ` | `.

Comment: @mudasobwa very interesting read. I guess I should have shared "effort" that went in, before asking a question and this is because we live in a world where there are way more people asking without prior "effort" that does not deserve the "effort" going in to answering it. Or as least in this site. Thank you for that. I thought I shouldn't bother others with what I've tried since I'm new and they are probably not worth sharing. As this is in public domain and others would look at it, my initial instinct was to stay away from sharing what I've tried, and ask for a more straightforward answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'll share what I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to iterate through values of `PROD_*` keys:

```
h = '{ ... }':

require 'json'

hash = (JSON.parse h).select { |k,v| k =~ /PROD_/ } # select PROD_* only

require 'csv'

CSV.open('filename', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << ['IMG', 'Name', 'Link', 'SEQ', 'Price', 'Mileage']
  hash.each { |k,v|
    csv << v.values
  }
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my direction wasn't too off =]

Comment: Sure. You proved that you have put some effort and we are here to help to fix the roughness. Now the whole page may be helpful for those came from google.